# Turn an html table into a selectable form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not looking for a specific example but more of if my process is right. 
I am making a fantasy football draft application and I have a table of draftable players. I'm trying to figure out how to let users select a player from the table and draft them. This is what I was thinking so far:

1. Instead of returning the table as html, return each row as a JS object
2. When a row is clicked, populate a hidden form with the player's ID
3. When the hidden form is populated enable a select button
4. When the form is submitted use js to add the player to the user's roster and rerender the table and player's rosters.

Does this make sense? I will be using jquery, but I have very limited experience with JS so I'm trying to break this down so I can learn.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the idea is reasonable but the implementation might be challenging especially for someone with limited experience.

Comment: This makes sense.  Just make sure to us use AJAX in (4) so that you don't have to re-render the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to look at [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) (although angular.js is another option)

Let's think about what you are trying to do mechanically. You have A User Interface (UI) which is your browsers DOM. The user is going to interact with this. Behind this, what you would like to have (although you haven't articulated it) is to have the underlying Model get updated as the user makes their choices.

You can do this essentially two ways. The first all JQuery & no ViewModel is to use click events and listeners and gather data manually, stick it into a form and post it via AJAX. You'll be crying in your lunchbox before long as your app grows more complex.

A better approach is to use a ViewModel - an in memory representation of your business objects. Think in terms of players, scores, rosters vs forms, textboxes, etc. How the magic works is using Knockout you can decorate your various HTML elements (input forms, labels, etc) using a technique called model-binding. Basically, you say a given input is an attribute on a given member of your ViewModel (VM). This removes all of the underlying plumbing from your concern and the UI and VM are kept in sync. From there, you can use Breeze.js to manage your communication of your VM to your web server. Angular is another approach, although I've not used it yet.

Now you might be wondering "I barely know JQuery, why do I need to run out and learn another library, I want to start building my app already". Well, JQuery is a library and Knockout is not. It is a framework. Think of a framework as a library, but with strong opinions about what you should do. Knockout also plays well with JQuery, but you really, really, really want to limit your DOM manipulation as much as possible.

You'll find lots of tutorials as well. http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro

Now some folks may point you in the direction of other competing frameworks. And you may eventually turn to Angular which is an "everything-in-one-box" approach, where as Knockout is more of a one-trick pony. But that is not really a weakness. Knockout does one thing well, and that's the thing you're after right now. Other libraries work well with it and you can add them as you learn, or migrate to Angular or whatever else as you learn and grow.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should use AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send the data to the server and update your table and roster. This way you don't have to fill a dummy form. You could add a `data-player="playerId"` to the table row and send this with your AJAX call.

You can use:

```
<tr data-id="foo" onclick="selectPlayer(this)">
  ..
</tr>
```

And the following code as an outline:

```
function selectPlayer(element) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '...',
    data: { playerId: $(this).data('id') }
  })
  .done(function (data) {
    // TODO: update roster & table
  });
```